# Need to find sample distribution with population distribution p given and sample size n given

Tags: statistics

A random sample of $100$ engineering students was chosen from Univesiti Teknologi Malaysia City Campus, Kuala Lumpur. $40\%$ of the students in the university work part time. The university authority wishes to know the following:

i) What percentage of the engineering students in the sample can be expected to have part time jobs?

ii) The probability of observing a sample proportion that is greater than $0.5$.

The answers for i) $0.4$ & ii) $0.0162$

For question 1 I'm not sure how to get the answer as in my view the confidence integers are not give and can't really be done while for question 2 the answer i got is $0.0207$ which is different than the given answers. Anyone can help explain? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

For i) the given answer is correct and it is simply due to the fact that

$$\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}_n]=\mu=40\%$$

For ii), using the continuity correction factor, you get

$$\mathbb{P}[\Sigma_i X_i>50]=1-\Phi\Big[\frac{50.5-40}{\sqrt{0.4\cdot0.6\cdot100}}\Big]=1-\Phi[2.14]\approx1.62\%$$

Your result is not wrong; simply you did not applied the continuity correction factor when approximating your discrete rv with a Gaussian.

Both results are an approximation of the true result.